# Websocket 431 error: Unexpected server response

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, binance

I have been building an application for myself to scan certain pumps etc. where I need the 1h and the 5m candle data to track such events. The code was working fine, untill it gave a 431 error: Unexpected server response. I am using c9 to code but I read that it was probably the websocket having to get to many request at once. So I tried putting a setInterval() in there, but still the same error.

Any suggestions on the code and how that problem is solved?

```
var market1h = 'not yet defined';
var market5m = 'not yet defined';

binance.prevDay(false, (error, prevDay) => {
    let markets = [];
    for ( let obj of prevDay ) {
        let symbol = obj.symbol;
        markets.push(symbol);
    }
    setInterval(get1hData, 1500);
    setInterval(get5mData, 1200);

    function get1hData(){
        binance.websockets.candlesticks(markets, '1h', (candlestickData) => {
        let tick = binance.last(candlestickData);
        market1h = candlestickData[tick];
        io.emit('market1h', market1h);
        });
    }
    function get5mData(){
        binance.websockets.candlesticks(markets, '5m', (candlestickData) => {
        let tick = binance.last(candlestickData);
        market5m = candlestickData[tick];
        io.emit("market5m", market5m);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

strlen(url.path) was the tipping point for me.

strlen 7929 = success

strlen 7942 = fail

I didn't find any official documentation on the 431 response. 
If I had to guess: Front end servers reject urls over a certain size; and don't make it to the back end servers for processing.

update:

> 431 Request Header Fields Too Large response status code indicates
>   that the server is unwilling to process the request because its header
>   fields are too large.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431